# Appending to lists in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to continually add values to a list; Keeping those values there until the program exits.

```
import sha1


def stored_hash(hash):
    hashes = [] 
    hash_extend = [hash]
    hashes.extend(hash_extend)
    return hashes

loop = 1
while loop == 1:
    data= raw_input('Enter text to hash: ')
    hash = sha1.run(data)
    store = stored_hash(hash)
    print store
```

I have a program called `sha1` that creates a hash of a input text. I want to store that hash in the list above `hashes` and be able to add more each time the loop completes so that my list is getting larger and larger.

How do I go about this? I'm a bit lost as to why I can't append a value to the end of a list and then print the whole list out with existing hash values present. All I get at the moment is one hash value no matter how many times the loop completes.

Do I need to make it a global list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass the list in as an argument:

```
import sha1

def stored_hash(store, hash):
    store.append(hash)

store = []
loop = 1
while loop == 1:
    data = raw_input('Enter text to hash: ')
    hash = sha1.run(data)
    stored_hash(store, hash)
    print store
```

Comment: ahhh this worked and is exactly what i was looking for. didn't even think to pass it as an argument. thanks a bunch. will answer this when it let's me.

Answer (score 1):

This line doesn't turn the contents of the variable `hash` to a list - it puts all that has been in there in a new fresh list:

```
hash_extend = [hash]
```

This is what you really want:

```
hash_extend = list(hash)
```

This way the contents of the variable `hash` will be turned into a list. For example:

```
>>> ls = [1,2,3]
>>> [ls]
[[1, 2, 3]]
>>> list(ls)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Also, if you just need to extend the list, you could skip the conversion to the list since I assume that the variable `hash` already contents an iterable:

```
def stored_hash(hash):
    hashes = []
    hashes.extend(hash)
    return hashes
```

Yet, this isn't going to extend the list every time you call the function. To do that, pass it to the function as a second argument:

```
def stored_hash(hash, prev_hash):
    prev_hash.extend(hash)
    return prev_hash
```

and call it like that:

```
store = stored_hash(hash, store)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be, you could declare the `hashes` list globally.

```
global hashes
hashes = []
```

Writing the above part would make it available globally in your program.